# Path variable works in bash but not found from apache

Tags: php, apache, matlab, path

I added the following path in `~/.bash_profile` in order to execute `matlab` from the terminal:

```
export PATH="/Applications/MATLAB_R2014b.app/bin:$PATH"
```

I am now able to execute a matlab function on the command line like this

```
matlab -r phpcreatefile"('example.txt')"
```

I want to do the exact same thing on php using `exec()`; however, it throws an error saying:

> sh: matlab: command not found.

Do I have to export a path in another configuration file in order to execute the matlab from my local apache server?

Comment: Likely apache is not running under your account

Comment: just use the full path in your exec command